# Elasticsearch and PHP. Combine match and multi_match in one query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have three fields - one of integer type (field1) and two of decimal type (field2, field3). I want to be able to query by all fields. These separate queries work nice in my situation:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'text_index_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'field1' => '12'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

and this query works well:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'text_index_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'multi_match' => [
                'query' => '345',
                'fields' => ['field2', 'field3']
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

If, however, I combine them:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'text_index_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'field1' => '12'
            ],
           'multi_match' => [
                'query' => '345',
                'fields' => ['field2', 'field3']
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

];

I get an error:

> Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception' ... [match] malformed query, unexpected [FIELD_NAME] found [multi_match]

So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it?

PS. In terms of SQL, this is what I want to achive:

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable where field1 = 12 or field2 = 345 or field3 = 345
```

Comment: By the way, it is a simplified query. In real world I will have much more fields, so I really need to use `multi_match`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine them with [bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html#_bool_queries)

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'test_index',
    'type' => 'test_index_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'field1' => '12' ] ],
                    [ 'multi_match' => [ 'query' => '345',
                                         'fields' => ['field2', 'field3']] ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

should equates to "OR" while must equates to "AND"